# Custom UITabBarController - DidSelect/AnyCustomization delegate problem

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I created custom TabBar class, but I have few problems, how I can call any function from this class when for example tab is hidden? (I would like to hide my stripe when tab bar is hidden) Also when I use `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3` the delegate didSelect is not called, how can I solve it? That is my simple code. Thanks for any help

```
class customTabBar: UITabBarController {


var stripe = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cellWidth = tabBar.frame.width/5
    stripe = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: tabBar.frame.minY + 20, width: (tabBar.frame.width/5) * 0.6, height: 6))
    stripe.center.x = cellWidth/2
    stripe.applyGradient(colours: [UIColor.init(hexFromString: "5897ee"),UIColor.init(hexFromString: "5228d8")])
    stripe.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    stripe.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.view.addSubview(stripe)

}

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    let index: Int = item.tag + 1
    let cellWidth = tabBar.frame.width/5
    let newPostion = cellWidth * CGFloat(index)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.3, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        self.stripe.center.x = newPostion - (cellWidth/2)

    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Add the stripe to tabBar，so it will hidden when tabBar hidden
        let cellWidth = tabBar.frame.width/5
        let stripe = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: tabBar.frame.minY + 20, width: (tabBar.frame.width/5) * 0.6, height: 6))
        stripe.center.x = cellWidth/2
        stripe.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        stripe.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.tabBar.addSubview(stripe)

    }

    //use this to observe tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
    override var selectedIndex: Int{
        didSet{
            //do what you want
        }
    }
}

extension UIViewController {

    //use this to call get MyTabBarController instance and call any function
    var myTabBarcontroller : MyTabBarController?{
        get{
            return self.tabBarController as? MyTabBarController
        }
    }
}
```